# Probability of selecting K elements of different probability from a set of N elemets

Tags: probability

I have a set of *N* elements. I want to select a few elements from the set. Now each element *i* of the set has a probability *P(i)* of getting selected. Then how can I figure out the probability of selecting at least *K* elements from the set?

Comment: Try this at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This an imprecise question. Are you selecting with exclusions, without ? It is best to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

To get it exact, you need inclusion/exclusion:
ie for each subset of k elements (i_1...i_k), add P(i_1)*P(i_2)...P(i_k)
Then for each subset of k+1 elements subtract:
P(i_1)*P(i_2)...P(i_k+1)
Then for each subset of k+2 elements add:
P(i_1)*P(i_2)...P(i_k+2)
and so on so forth alternately adding and subtracting until you reach n or the terms become negligible.

Alternatively, if k is smaller than N/2 you can go the other way:
Start with 1
For all subsets of n-k+1 elements subtract:
(1-P(i_1))*(1-P(i_2))*(1-P(i_3))...(1-P(i_n-k+1))
then for all subsets of n-k+2 elements add:
(1-P(i_1))*(1-P(i_2))*(1-P(i_3))...(1-P(i_n-k+2))
then for all subsets of n-k+3 elements subtract:
(1-P(i_1))*(1-P(i_2))*(1-P(i_3))...(1-P(i_n-k+3))
and so on so forth alternately adding and subtracting until you reach n or the terms become negligible.